# How to move the selected Item in the menu to the center

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/50/

I am using swiper min js fro my Application to display the menu .

I am able to display the menu .

My question is that , is it possible to move the Selected / Clicked item in the menu to move it to the center ??

This is my code for displaying the menu

```
var T1categories = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE" , "FOUR" , "FIVE" ];
createhorizontaltab(T1categories);

function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
    var categoryArr = categories;
    var favoriteresultag = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.length; i++) {
        favoriteresultag += '<div class="swiper-slide"><span>' + categoryArr[i] + '</span></div>';
    }
    $("#swipecontainer").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");
}
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
    $('.swiper-slide').removeClass('swiper-slide-active');
    $(this).addClass('swiper-slide-active');
});
```

please let me know how to do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I determined the center of the menu with giving an id, which is **center**, while creating these elements. Then I change the text of clicked span with the span, whose id is **center**.

```
    var T1categories = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE" , "FOUR" , "FIVE" ];
    createhorizontaltab(T1categories);

    function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
        var categoryArr = categories;
        var favoriteresultag = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.length; i++) {
            if(i!=2) {/* I assumed you always have five spans for the menu*/
                favoriteresultag += '<div class="swiper-slide"><span>' + categoryArr[i] + '</span></div>';
            }
            else {
                favoriteresultag += '<div class="swiper-slide" id="center"><span>' + categoryArr[i] + '</span></div>';
            }
        }
        $("#swipecontainer").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");
    }
    $(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
        var str = $(this).text();
        var str2 = $("#center").text();
        $(this).removeClass('swiper-slide-active');
        $(this).children().text(str2);
        $("#center").children().text(str);
        $("#center").addClass('swiper-slide-active');
    });
```

This approach could give you an idea.

Comment: This is definately a starting point for me to proceed further . (The only problem i am facing is that the length of the menu is not fixed)

Comment: I  resolved the issue by using 
        var centervalue = Math.floor(categoryArr.length/2);